# XMLElement function Encoding XML <> to &lt; and &gt;

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, psql

I want to build some xml starting with the inner XML and then adding outer XML.  Here's a simplification of my code:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  v_xml           text;
  cmd             text;
BEGIN
  cmd := 'select xmlelement(name myelement, ''test'')';
  EXECUTE cmd INTO v_xml;
  v_xml := xmlelement(name parentXMl, v_xml);
  RETURN v_xml;
END;
$$
```

I would expect this code to return:

```
<parentxml><myelement>test</myelement></parentxml>
```

Instead it returns:

```
<parentxml>&lt;myelement&gt;test&lt;/myelement&gt;</parentxml>
```

How can I stop XMLElement() from encoding my XML to XML values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember, element names should always be quoted

if you want to generate xml data as text values, don't forget to cast it to xml afterwards

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  v_xml           text;
  cmd             text;
BEGIN
  cmd := 'select xmlelement(name "myelement", ''test'')';
  EXECUTE cmd INTO v_xml;
  v_xml := xmlelement(name "parentXMl", v_xml::xml);
  RETURN v_xml::xml;
END;
$$
```

Dimitry is right you should better declare V_xml as an xml variable.

Comment: The cast of v_xml to xml worked.  As you said declaring the v_xml as xml is best instead of casting it.

Answer (score 2):

Types for variables `v_xml`,`cmd` should be [`XML`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-xml.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testxml() RETURNS XML AS $$
DECLARE
  v_xml           XML;
  cmd             XML;
BEGIN
  cmd := 'select xmlelement(name myelement, ''test'')';
  EXECUTE cmd INTO v_xml;
  v_xml := xmlelement(name parentXMl, v_xml);
  RETURN v_xml;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result is:

```
ds=# select testxml();                                                                                                                          testxml                       
----------------------------------------------------
 <parentxml><myelement>test</myelement></parentxml>
(1 row)
```

Comment: why did you declare cmd as xml?